# Linking one xcode project from another

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I have two xcode project for example **A** and **B**. I include project **B** into A and try to import some header files of project B. Project B is built successfully but when I try to build project **A** It throws error as header file not found. How can I resolve this?

Comment: set header search path in build settings

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, for Project A check your build settings->Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths. Do they contain the path of the header files for Project B? If not, add the path in one of these fields.

Watch out:

Including a header in a Header Search Path involves writing this:

```
#import <header.h>
```

whereas importing a header in a User Header Search Path involves this:

```
#import "header.h"
```

I would recommend putting it in the Header Search paths to distinguish including headers from project A and project B in your code. It improves readability in my opinion.